# Can't write HFS+ in OS X

Tags: windows, macos, hfs+

I've an external HDD of 500GB and in HFS+ format. It works normally on my Mac running OS X 10.5.8. After I plugged it into a machine running Windows, I found a vacant partition of 128MB and formatted it to NTFS. I used Paragon HFS+ for Windows to read and copy files.

Now I'm not able to write to that disk on my Mac. What is the problem?

Comment: "Not able to write" with which symptoms? Can't you copy files there or create new ones? Or do you get any errors? What's the output of `diskutil list`?

Comment: Hi, this problem has been solved by booting in to the Lion Setup disk and using the disk utility to repair it, now it's working fine.

Comment: Then please answer your own question using the button below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem has been solved by booting in to the Lion Setup disk and using the disk utility to repair it, now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the 128MB partition had important information for the Mac OS (which you erased when formatting it). It sounds like you have read access, so the simple solution is to copy everything off of it (back it up), and then reformat it for hfs+, then move the backups back onto the drive.

Regardless of the method(s) you may find to attempt to fix this without reformatting the drive, I would back up anything important so that if you lose read access to the drive's current state, you don't lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can help your problem

1. sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsprogs hfsutils libhfsp0
2. ALT + F2, type gksudo nautilus
3. please access the HFS + partition
4. test creating and deleting files

Comment: Hi, this problem has been solved by booting in to the Lion Setup disk and using the disk utility to repair it, now it's working fine.